How to increase the cardinality of this set?
Our set theory professor gave us an example that seems very counterintuitive to me.
We have the set of all points in $\Bbb R^3$.
Now I know this has the cardinality continuum because $\Bbb R^n$ is equipotent with $\Bbb R$ for any given finite $n$.
The points do not only have the three coordinates specifying the position in space but also the color of the point.
Now the question:

How many different colors must we have such that the cardinality of the set of all possible colorings exceeds $P(\Bbb R)$?

I thought about this and my intuition is that finitely many colors would not suffice so we need to have at least countably infinitely many.
And what's the cardinality of the set of all subsets of this set?
The problem is that this is supposed to be a tricky question and this answer seems very intuitive and almost trivial so it's probably not right or there is some catch. Can you help me ?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Are you sure that countably many colors are enough? How would you prove it?

Are you saying each point in $\mathbb R^3$ has a particular colour drawn from a set of colours?  That would not affect the number of points.  Or that you have coincident points with different colours?  Even then, if the set of colours was had the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$, your set of coloured points would be no larger than $\mathbb R^4$, which has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.  Or are you trying to count the number of different ways of colouring $\mathbb R^3$?

@Henry thanks for the insight I reread the question and now I think my edit makes it clear. The question is asking me to.increase the cardinality of all possible colorings.

Hint: Why will 2 colors be the same as the power set of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

@MichaelBurr because then for each point we can assign two values let's say white or black which is the same procedure we use to determine if an element is part of a subset. That's why I think finitely many colors wouldn't be enough.

Think about the cardinalities of $2^{\mathbb R^3}$ and $\mathbb N^{\mathbb R^3}$ and $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^3}$, or perhaps simpler of  $2^{\mathbb R}$ and $\mathbb N^{\mathbb R}$  and $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, or indeed of $2^\kappa$ and $\kappa^\kappa$ for an infinite cardinal $\kappa$.

@Henry. This is what I find confusing. Even if we have continuum many colors then each point can be represented by four real numbers, three spatial and one color coordinate. This makes it an element of R^4 so as you said earlier the cardinality of this space doesn't exceed the continuum and the number of coloring is P(R). I know some cardinal arithmetic but I can't seem to make the critical connection between it and the colors. What do the colors represent in this case?

@Karl for two colors that seems like P(R). For what number of colors does that exceed P(R) ?

I accidentally deleted my comment, but I think the problem with your intuition is that you're confusing the domain and codomain of the coloring function by bundling the coordinates with the color. Where are you getting the $P$ when you go from $\Bbb R^4$ to $P(\Bbb R^4)$?

@Karl Here is my intuition. Let's say we want to color the whole of R^3 red. Then this particular coloring seems to be a subset of R^4 namely the set of all elements of the form (x, y ,z , red) so all the colorings must be the powerset of R^4

I see now, sorry! It seems that even $|P(\Bbb R)|$ colors is insufficient, since $2^R=2^{R\times R}=(2^R)^R$ by currying.

FYI, OP reasked this on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/483086/506492
